# removing rows with any column containing NaN, NaTs, and nans

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

Currently I have data as below:

```
df_all.head()
Out[2]: 
   Unnamed: 0 Symbol       Date      Close       Weight
0        4061      A 2016-01-13  36.515889   (0.000002)
1        4062     AA 2016-01-14  36.351784    0.000112 
2        4063    AAC 2016-01-15  36.351784   (0.000004)
3        4064    AAL 2016-01-19  36.590483    0.000006 
4        4065   AAMC 2016-01-20  35.934062    0.000002 

df_all.tail()
Out[3]: 
         Unnamed: 0 Symbol Date  Close Weight
1252498    26950320    nan  NaT   9.84    NaN
1252499    26950321    nan  NaT  10.26    NaN
1252500    26950322    nan  NaT   9.99    NaN
1252501    26950323    nan  NaT   9.11    NaN
1252502    26950324    nan  NaT   9.18    NaN

df_all.dtypes
Out[4]: 
Unnamed: 0             int64
Symbol                object
Date          datetime64[ns]
Close                float64
Weight                object
dtype: object
```

As can be seen, I am getting values in Symbol of nan, Nat for Date and NaN for weight.

MY GOAL: I want to remove any row that has ANY column containing nan, Nat or NaN and have a new df_clean to be the result

I don't seem to be able to apply the appropriate filter?  I am not sure if I have to convert the datatypes first (although I tried this as well)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, the symbol '`nan'` is not caught by `dropna()` or `isnull()`. You need to cast the symbol`'nan'` as `np.nan`

Try this:

```
 df["symbol"] = np.where(df["symbol"]=='nan',np.nan, df["symbol"] )
 df.dropna()
```

Comment: Would like to hear rationale for the downvote! Getting lucky because 'nan' happens to be in the same row NaT or NaN, does not assure that it will be removed.

Comment: .@Ami Glad you edited your answer! after I pointed the error in logic. The code as written fails. did you test it?

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
df_all.replace({'nan': None})[~pd.isnull(df_all).any(axis=1)]
```

This is because `isnull` recognizes both `NaN` and `NaT` as "null" values.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @John Note that I've updated your question, as the title could better reflect that what you need to remove is not only `NaN`s, but also `NaT`s and `nan`s. This required a small update here as well.

Comment: Wouldn't `df_all.replace({'nan': None}).dropna()` be better here?